# jspdf file sizes are quite huge for text only

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I've done my PDF uploading service using jspdf, which might be a mistake looking back.
Anyway i have no time to refactor the whole module today so i try to come up with solution
to reduces pdf sizes.

```
    const info
    const infos
    etc...

    const header = function (res) {
        ... ommitted
    }

    const footer = function (res) {
        ... ommitted
    }

    const y = 40
    const x = 15

    //INTRO
    pdf.setFontSize(10)
    pdf.text(x, y, info.name, {
    })
    pdf.text(x, y+6, info.address)
    pdf.text(x + 165, y+6, info.pvm)

    //HEADER
    pdf.setFontSize(15)
    pdf.setFontType("bold")
    pdf.text(x, y + 30, text)

    //TEXT CONTENT
    pdf.setFontType("normal")
    pdf.setFontSize(10)
    pdf.text(x, y + 40, trailer)


    //FOOTER
    pdf.setFontSize(5)
    pdf.text(x, height - 25, infos)


    pdf.addPage()

    pdf.autoTable(columns, rows,
        {
            margin: { top: 25, bottom: 30 },
            styles: {
                overflow: 'linebreak',
                fontSize: 4
            },
            showHeader: 'everyPage',
            afterPageContent: footer,
            beforePageContent: header,
            theme: 'plain',
            drawCell: function (cell, data) {
                if (cell.text === " ") {
                    pdf.addPage()
                    }
                }
        })
        if (typeof pdf.putTotalPages === 'function') {
            pdf.putTotalPages(totalPagesExp)
        }
    this.pdfSender(pdf.output(), cus)
};
```

This code will generate 2.1mb pdf file with 40 pages.
Old solution was 632kb for 85 pages..
There is not a single image in pdf
just a very very basic text table.

I would love some insight on how i would possibly reduce the size of this pdf.
it also needs to be send to backend as byte[]

omitted variables and footer & header are just lots and lots of text